# configuring Artifactory Jenkins error in windows

Tags: artifactory

On windows I have installed **Artifactory 4.11.0 and jenkins 1.643**.
Both are running separately fine. I have also installed **artifactory plugin 2.10.4** and tried to configure by providing default credentials and when used test connection check it is throwing the following error.

What can I do. Do I have to configure something special in Artifactory ?

**Please see the following error**

```
Stack trace
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 
        "org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider
        (Lorg/apache/http/client/CredentialsProvider;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;" 
        the class loader (instance of hudson/ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2) of the current class,
        org/jfrog/build/client/PreemptiveHttpClient, and the class loader 
       (instance of hudson/ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2) for resolved class,
        org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder, have different Class objects for the type 
        he.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider
        (Lorg/apache/http/client/CredentialsProvider;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
        used in the signature
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)


at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
... 59 more
```

Comment: This seems to be caused by a conflict with another Jenkins Plugin, which uses an older Http Client version. Upgrading the relevant plugin may resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of upgrading downgraded the plugin. It is working